# require.ensure error in React Code Splitting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm using react-router's code splitting(Dynamic Routing). When building app from webpack it doesn't give error, but when running it, it is giving me error of `require.ensure is not a function`. I'm using server-side rendering also.

Following is my getComponent code

```
module.exports = {
path: "/",
getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, require('./component/Home'));
    })
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think server side render doesn't support `require.ensure`, because node has its own `require`, and when you use server side render, it will use `node require`, not `webpack require`.

I think you should try to user different routes for server and client. the server routes don't use `dynamic route`